# Getting position of track and sector in 'dd'-created floppy image

Tags: images, dd, floppy, binary-files

I got some floppy images (original DOS 6.22 und FreeDOS  1.44 MB boot disks) created using the *nix `dd`command that work fine when used in a virtual environment.

Now I want to understand the structure of these files.

As far as I know a 1.44 MB floppy disk has **80 tracks**, each track has **18 sectors** and each sector consists of **512 bytes**. Multiplying this gets me to about 0.7MB which is exactly the size of one of the **two sides**.

The position of track 0 sector 2 head 2 is 9728 (or 0x2600) - this is the first sector the DOS 6.22 bootloader fetches from the disk. But how is this calculated?

How do I get to these values? I used an emulator to step through the bootloader. The first floppy access is done by calling interrupt 013h with AH = 2 (read from floppy), AL = 1 (read one sector), CH = 0 (read from track 0), CL = 2 (read from sector 2) and DH = 1 (use head 1 = use second side). This call gets the emulator to load the bytes starting at position 9728.

Each register value except of the sector number (which is 1-based) is 0-based.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the emulator need to pass the address to the virtual disk drive to indicate which physical disk location to retrieve the data from?  It's also possible that the emulator uses a base-offset addressing scheme for the virtual disk driver, or positions the "disk head" before the first read call.  Also, *what emulator are you using?*

Comment: @Breakthrough The emulator is called *emu8086*. Nevertheless the image works with VMWare Player as well. Of course it needs to pass the address to the virtual disk drive, but I don't have access to it - it just accesses the floppy image. I disassembled the bootloader code, and this really is the second interrupt call at all (the first one is Int 13h as well with AH = 00 to reset the disk drive). Therefore the adress parameteres (register values) don't have anything to do with the emulator that is used, do they?

Comment: correct, in this case they don't have anything to do with the particular emulator.  I re-read your question in this light, and am not sure what you are asking.  Do you want to know how the actual offset `0x2600` is calculated from the passed register values (AH, AL, CH, CL, DH)?

Comment: @Breakthrough yes, I just want to know how this offset is calculated. That's all ;)

Comment: @Breakthrough I added the details. Accepting my own answer isn't possible atm, but I'm going to make up for it asap.

Comment: there might be a 24 hour delay, my apologies.  Regardless, nice answer, I was curious how it worked as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The file is structured in the [LBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) format, which can be easily calculated from the [CHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_Head_Sector) values I got:

> LBA = (cylinder * number_of_heads + head) * sectors_per_track + sector
>   - 1
>
> = (0 * 2 + 1) * 18 + 2 - 1 = 19
>
> 19 * bytes_per_sector = 19 * 512 = **9728**